# Creating registration form using Java and connect it with online database

Tags: java, mysql

I am required to create a JAVA project to implement a system where user can register and login through it and make a reservation for a restaurant. This JAVA program must be able to run on any computer. So what can I do to implement this system? Do I need MySQL or SQLite or anything?

I had tried to use Google MySQL cloud, I already create the GUI and it only works for my PC but not others. What system should I use to store the data user?
[This image is from my friend PC that tried to use my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOaho.png)

Comment: of course you need to have some DBMS like `MySQL` or `SQLite` to manage database for your application. If your looking for portable DB which can easily be distributed with `jar` then `SQLite` might be helpful

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.... I am looking for a system that allow user to login to the system wherever they are ( connect to internet). What should I use? SQlite right?